# Open EdX (Bitnami install) fails Gmail authentication for email registration.

Tags: json, django, email, bitnami, openedx

**I am unable to get Open EdX to authenticate to my Gmail account to send registration emails.** Here's what I'm working with:

- New installation of Open EdX via Bitnami.
- Edited lms.env.json and cms.env.json based on [this guide from the Bitnami wiki](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Open_edX#SMTP_configure_for_Gmail), including adding EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD fields.
- Recompiled and restarted server.
- Registered a new user and got a successful response via the LMS (account created and let me in).
- However, no email confirmation came through.
- Google account that I'm using [allows access for less secure apps.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)
- Log shows the following:

  > File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 731, in sendmail
  >   raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
  >   SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1       support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 x123sm6973392pfb.54 - gsmtp', u'nyedid@sandtontechnologies.com')
  >   2016-05-10 19:22:38,850 INFO 13202 [audit] models.py:1802 - Login success - user.id: 5
  >   2016-05-10 19:22:38,919 INFO 13202 [audit] views.py:1822 - Login success on new account creation - Test2
- I can log in to the account with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided in the error message (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257) notes that you may receive this error if you have 2-factor authentication enabled on your account. In that case, you should generate an App Password (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#ASPs) specifically for your Open edX instance, and use that in place of your normal GMail password.

Does that help?